# After removed css, why is it taking same effect?

Tags: html, css, angular13

Here I am adding images of my work. I stuck here because after removing CSS it's still working.
see in this image.[In this image it has width:30%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2NnU.png) when I have been removed in my project [my source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWxpA.png). How can I remove it? what is the problem that I found this type of error?
I have also checked to do a hard refresh(ctrl+f5)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your file. It looks like the file hasn't been saved yet.